# Powershell script to check if users in an csv file are existing in AD and to create 2 output lists

Tags: powershell

I am not really good at scripting, but I tried for a couple of hours to create a  script which will look through a UserList.csv and will output: 1. existingAccounts.txt 2.NotExistingAccounts.txt. It works but I would like for 1. existingAccounts.txt to include also Properties like: Description,Email of the accounts.

the script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList = get-content E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\UserList.csv
Foreach ($Item in $UserList) {
$user = $null
$user =  Get-aduser -filter {samAccountName -eq $Item}
if ($user)
    {
    $user | Out-File E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\existingAccounts.txt -encoding default -append
    }
    else
    {
    "$item does not exist" | Out-File E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\NotExistingAccounts.txt -encoding default -append
    }
}
```

`existingAccounts.txt` produces:

```
DistinguishedName : CN=John DOE,OU=BOF
                    Management,OU=Privileged,OU=BOF,OU=Accounts,OU=KADEN,DC=DRUI,DC=PASXO,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : John
Name              : John Doe
ObjectClass       : user
SamAccountName    : john.doe
Surname           : Doe
UserPrincipalName : john.doe@BOF.kaden.com
```

`NotExistingAccounts.txt` produces

```
user does not exist
```

please help

Comment: It's better to use `Import-Csv` to read CSV data (if it really is a CSV - CSV means "comma-separated values" and, while text, is in a specific format).

Comment: In addition to Bill's comment, the best output type would be a Csv for found users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific set of properties that `Get-ADUser` will bring for an AD User by default, you need to specify other properties you want to bring using the `-Properties` parameter (such as `Description` and `mail`)

This code sample should bring those properties you're looking for and export the users to a CSV file. Try it out.

Remove `Select-Object samAccountName, Description, Mail` at the end if you want to bring the default properties plus the ones you needed.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList = Get-Content E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\UserList.csv
$hash = @{
    Properties = 'Description','mail'
}

$foundUsers = foreach($Item in $UserList)
{
    $hash.LDAPFilter = "(|(samAccountName=$item)(name=$item))"
    Get-ADUser @hash

    if ($user)
    {
        $user
        continue
    }
    
    "$item does not exist" |
    Out-File E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\NotExistingAccounts.txt -encoding Default -Append
}

$foundUsers | Select-Object samAccountName, Description, Mail |
Export-Csv E:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\existingAccounts.csv -NoTypeInformation
```